# Using ORDER BY while still maintaining use of index

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I'd like to retrieve some rows utilizing my index on Columns A and B. I was told the only way to ensure my index is being used to retrieve the rows is to use an ORDER by clause, for example:

```
A  B  offset
1  5   1
1  4   2
2  5   3
2  4   4

SELECT A,B FROM TableX 
WHERE offset > 0 AND offset < 5 
ORDER BY A,B ASC
```

but then I would like my results for just those rows returned to be ordered by column B and not A,B.

```
A  B
1  4  
2  4    
2  5   
1  5
```

How can I do this and still ensure my index is being used and not a full table scan? If I was to use ORDER BY B then doesn't this mean MySQL will scan by B and defeat the purpose of having the two column index?

Comment: Are you sure a full table scan will be slower? The optimizer generally chooses full table scan when a sufficient amount of rows can be expected to be returned.

Comment: Add an index on B, and run `EXPLAIN your-query`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any index that includes A or B cloumns will have no effect on your query, regardless of your `ORDER BY`. You need an index on `offset` as that is the field that is being used in hte `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but maybe I did not understand the question..

The above output query should result:

```
A   B
1   4
1   5
2   4
2   5
```

For avoiding table scan, you should add an index for the offset and use it in your WHERE clause.

If possible to use unique then use it.

> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX offsetidx ON TableX (offset);

or

> CREATE INDEX offsetidx ON TableX (offset);

Comment: Sorry I wrote this question so poorly. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your query, the best index is probably `(offset,A,B)`. This will allow the optimizer to use the leftmost part of the index to honor the `WHERE` clause, and the rest of the index allowing to use [merge sort](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-merge-optimization.html).

```
ALTER TABLE TableX ADD INDEX (offset,A,B);
```

In order to take full advantage of that, the query has to be rewritten as:

```
SELECT A,B FROM TableX 
WHERE offset BETWEEN 0 AND 5 
ORDER BY A,B;
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8e718/2